# Writing a shapefile using OGR, from Shapely Geometry - No feature added Error

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, ogr, shapely

I am trying to write a shapefile from a Shapely geometry using PyQGIS in the QGIS 2.6.0 console.

**Lines of code before the OGR method to write shapefile:**

```
extnt = poly.extent() # gives a QtRectangle output -> extnt
x_min = extnt.xMinimum()
x_max = extnt.xMaximum()
y_min = extnt.yMinimum()
y_max = extnt.yMaximum()

A_bbox = QgsPoint(x_min, y_min)
B_bbox = QgsPoint(x_max, y_min)
C_bbox = QgsPoint(x_max, y_max)
D_bbox = QgsPoint(x_min, y_max)
```

where poly is a polygon shapefile.

Source for the Code below :- [How to write Shapely geometries to shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/how-to-write-shapely-geometries-to-shapefiles) and [GitHub post](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html)

```
linelyr = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
linelyr.AddPoint(x_min, y_min)
linelyr.AddPoint(x_min, y_max)
out_line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
out_line.AddGeometry(linelyr)
out_line.ExportToWkb

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("Esri Shapefile")
ds = driver.CreateDataSource("outputlocation.shp")
layr1 = ds.CreateLayer('', None, ogr.wkbLineString)

layr1.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger))
defn = layr1.GetLayerDefn()

feat = ogr.Feature(defn)
feat.SetField('id', 1)

geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(out_line.wkb) # or maybe just 'outline'
feat.SetGeometry(geom)

layr1.CreateFeature(feat)
ds = layr1 = feat = geom = None
```

The shapefile is created, along with all the necessary files, meaning **no errors**. But the shapefile, when opened in QGIS has no features. Just a constructed attribute table.

Pls assist...

P. S. **Any Other solution besides OGR usage also works, as long as it can be coded in the Python console of QGIS**

Comment: Does it need the 1st point as the 5th point to close the polygon?

Comment: Nope. A, B, C, D (anti-clockwise) are the vertices of the bounding box of the polygon shapefile. I am trying to draw the A-D line segment and export it as a shapefile. To add some context: I will draw lines parallel to this A-D line along the entire bounding box

Comment: Do you need to close the shape file at the end, I'm not really familiar with Pyqgis.

Comment: Here is some additional information that even I am looking through.. You could help out if you are familiar with Python atleast. Look through the question hyperlinked in the above post and also [Vector Layer information from PyQGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some remarks because you mix many things ( if you want yo use your script outside the console of QGIS, install the Python module [GDAL (osgeo)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.11.1) in your Python installation: it is installed in the Python version of QGIS if you are on Windows).

1) **There are no [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) geometries** in your script, only

- PyQGIS geometries `QgsPoint(x_min, y_min)`, ...
- ogr geometries `linelyr = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)`, ...

2) `out_line` is unnecessary because `linelyr` is already an ogr LineString (and your creation of `out_line` gives invalid geometries (empty LineStrings =  LineString(LineString))

```
linelyr = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
linelyr.AddPoint(5, 47)
linelyr.AddPoint(5, 55)
print linelyr.ExportToJson()
{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 5.0, 47.0, 0.0 ], [ 5.0, 55.0, 0.0 ] ] }
# and
out_line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
out_line.AddGeometry(linelyr)
print out_line.ExportToWkt()
LINESTRING EMPTY
```

3) In the same way, you don't need `geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(out_line.wkb)` because as said, `out_line` or `linelyr` are already ogr LineStrings.

3) At the end of the process, with ogr, if you not close the resulting shapefile, it remains empty.

So:

```
from osgeo import ogr
# create ogr geometry
linelyr = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
linelyr.AddPoint(5, 47)
linelyr.AddPoint(5, 55)
# create the shapefile
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("Esri Shapefile")
ds = driver.CreateDataSource("outputlocation.shp")
layr1 = ds.CreateLayer('',None, ogr.wkbLineString)
# create the field
layr1.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger))
# Create the feature and set values
defn = layr1.GetLayerDefn()
feat = ogr.Feature(defn)
feat.SetField('id', 1)
feat.SetGeometry(linelyr)
layr1.CreateFeature(feat)
# close the shapefile
ds.Destroy()
```

[image]

If you want to use [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html):

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
line = LineString([Point(5,47),Point(5,55)])
# conversion to ogr geometry
linelyr = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(line.wkt)
print linelyr.ExportToJson()
{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 5.0, 47.0, 0.0 ], [ 5.0, 55.0, 0.0 ] ] }
```

If you want to use PyQGIS:

```
line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(5,47),QgsPoint(5,55)]))
# conversion to ogr geometry
linelyr = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(line.exportToWkt())
print linelyr.ExportToJson()
{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 5.0, 47.0 ], [ 5.0, 55.0 ] ] }
```

Comment: Just a clarification... If I had to add multiple lines, I would have to run a loop. Would a for loop from before `Add.Point()` and ending after `feat.SetGeometry()` suffice? Considering I have to draw equally spaced parallel lines, increasing the `x` coordinate by a fixed distance.

Comment: before `linelyr = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)`and after `layr1.CreateFeature(feat)` otherwise no line is created