# Dissolving polygons based on multiple attributes with Python (shapely and fiona)?

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, fiona

I would like to dissolve a polygon shapefile based on two different fields, using Python and open source libraries.

I'm just able to dissolve the shapefile using one single field, with Gene's answer to [Dissolving polygons based on attributes with Python (shapely, fiona)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149959/dissolving-polygons-based-on-attributes-with-python-shapely-fiona)

Here's the code he suggests, that should be the starting point for what I need:

```
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping
from shapely.ops import unary_union
import fiona
import itertools
with fiona.open('cb_2013_us_county_20m.shp') as input:
    # preserve the schema of the original shapefile, including the crs
    meta = input.meta
    with fiona.open('dissolve.shp', 'w', **meta) as output:
        # groupby clusters consecutive elements of an iterable which have the same key so you must first sort the features by the 'STATEFP' field
        e = sorted(input, key=lambda k: k['properties']['STATEFP'])
        # group by the 'STATEFP' field 
        for key, group in itertools.groupby(e, key=lambda x:x['properties']['STATEFP']):
            properties, geom = zip(*[(feature['properties'],shape(feature['geometry'])) for feature in group])
            # write the feature, computing the unary_union of the elements in the group with the properties of the first element in the group
            output.write({'geometry': mapping(unary_union(geom)), 'properties': properties[0]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change two `key=lambda k: k['properties']['FIELD']` parts into `key=lambda k: (k['properties']['FIELD_1'], k['properties']['FIELD_2'])`.

Shortly, you have to use `('field_1', 'field_2')` tuple instead of `'field'`.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping
from shapely.ops import unary_union
import fiona
import itertools

with fiona.open('source.shp') as input:
    meta = input.meta
    with fiona.open('target.shp', 'w', **meta) as output:
        # First, sort data by field_1 then field_2
        e = sorted(input, key=lambda k: (k['properties']['FIELD_1'], k['properties']['FIELD_2']) )
        # group by field_1 then filed_2 
        for key, group in itertools.groupby(e, key=lambda k: (k['properties']['FIELD_1'], k['properties']['FIELD_2'])):
            properties, geom = zip(*[(feature['properties'], shape(feature['geometry'])) for feature in group])
            output.write({'geometry': mapping(unary_union(geom)), 'properties': properties[0]})
```