# Is there a python-module to convert data to a Shapefile (w/o GIS)?

Tags: python, shapefile, software-recommendations

Input data can be excel, text, whatever. I would like to produce shapefiles from data on a computer without GIS installed. Is there anything out there?

Fiona seems to be such a module.  Are there any other modules? Is Fiona the best choice?

I have data in a list like this:

```
mylist = [["lat1","long1","lat2","long2","var1","var2","var3"],
         [55.000,7.000,54.000,6.000,30,40,50]
         [54.000,6.000,52.000,8.000,30,40,50]
         [52.000,8.000,53.000,7.000,30,40,50]
         [53.000,7.000,50.000,6.000,30,40,50]
         [50.000,6.000,55.000,7.000,30,40,50]]
```

And I would like to make a shapefile (polyline) out of that.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/how-to-write-shapely-geometries-to-shapefiles) question could be of help:

Comment: You don't seem to have grasped what is wrong with your question(s). If people ask for clarification, there is a clue there.

Comment: [Pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) is an open source pure Python module that allows you to generate shapefiles without any dependencies.  I have used this quite a bit and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [fiona](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html) module would do, but in a sense you are then adding some GIS functionnalities to Python. Further GIS-like analysis on the geometries can then be performed using shapely.