# Getting CRS to export shapely polygon to shapefile

Tags: shapefile, export, shapely, fiona

I am trying to export a shapely polygon to a shapefile. [I have tried this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/how-to-write-shapely-geometries-to-shapefiles), but the CRS is missing, when I try to import it in to QGIS.

The shapely polygon is from [this OSMNX example](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb) but edited to work with location.

My (list of two) polygons:

```
In [68]:

isochrone_polys


Out[68]:
[<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1d884a52cc0>,
 <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x1d883974f60>]
```

I tried this using Fiona:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
Proj(isochrone_polys[0].crs)
```

But have an attribute error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-f3e93644040a> in <module>
      2 import fiona
      3 from fiona.crs import from_epsg
----> 4 Proj(isochrone_polys[0].crs)

AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

The edges in and nodes in the street network in the tutorial seem to be in 4326, but when I put this in as the CRS in QGIS, it was incorrect.

`edges` is a geopandas dataframe, while the `isochrone_polys[1]` is in shapely.

```
type(edges)
Out[11]: geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame

type(isochrone_polys[1])
Out[12]: shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon

print(edges.crs)
+proj=utm +zone=55 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

print(isochrone_polys[1].crs)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-e4c06ab91976>", line 1, in <module>
    print(isochrone_polys[1].crs)

AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

The polygon itself seems to be in a projected coordinate system (not sure which one):

```
isochrone_polys[0].bounds
Out[7]: 
(316180.5323058479,
 -4182505.539783961,
 317463.60173865134,
 -4181214.9721103134)
```

How would I export this properly with the correct CRS?

Comment: More information added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/how-to-write-shapely-geometries-to-shapefiles?noredirect=1&lq=1) that you tried didn't set CRS so when you import the shapefile into QGIS. It's incorrect.

If you know the CRS is EPSG 4326, then you can set it while creating the shapefile like this:

```
from osgeo import osr, ogr # import osr, ogr 
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource('abc.shp')
lyr = ds.CreateLayer('route', sr, ogr.wkbPolygon)
```

**NEW UPDATE:**

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import shapely.wkt

# read wkt and use it to create a shapely polygon P
with open('/Users/**/osmnx_test-master/isochrone_polys_0.txt') as f:
    x = f.readline()
P = shapely.wkt.loads(x)

# Now convert it to a shapefile with OGR    
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
# or sr.ImportFromProj4(edges.crs)
sr.ImportFromProj4('+proj=utm +zone=55 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource('abc.shp')
layer = ds.CreateLayer('route', sr, ogr.wkbPolygon)# Add one attribute
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger))
defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()

## If there are multiple geometries, put the "for" loop here

# Create a new feature (attribute and geometry)
feat = ogr.Feature(defn)
feat.SetField('id', 123)

# Make a geometry, from Shapely object
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(P.wkb)
feat.SetGeometry(geom)
layer.CreateFeature(feat)
feat =  None 

# Save and close the data source
ds = None
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I couldn't get it to work though. Is this standalone? I could only get it to work by replacing `route` with `isochrone_polys[0]` but I imagine that isn't correct and produces an empty shapefile anyway. Adding it to the original code (replacing the other bits) also didn't seem to work well.

Comment: The `route` in `lyr = ds.CreateLayer('route', sr, ogr.wkbPolygon)`  is just a new layer named in Shapefile, you can name it whatever you want. And this method works with the GDAL/OGR, which you don't need to use Fiona. The basic idea is to create a new shapefile with the CRS you want and add shapely geometry to each feature in the shapefile by `geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(isochrone_polys[0].wkb)` following the link you provided.

Comment: I have tried that and still can't get it to work. It exports the `abc.shp` that is empty when I open it in QGIS.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: In here: https://github.com/william3031/osmnx_test Thanks.

Comment: I have added a python script which has pretty much the same information as the notebook. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I checked your code. First, you should delete the parts of test1 and test2, just use test3. Because I am not familiar with networkx, therefore I created a polygon in shapely to simulate the isochrone_polys[0]. And it works, check my update in my answer where I added the code.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Yes, it does work with `Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 100), (100, 0)])` as the coordinates fit in to a WGS84 structure but it doesn't with `isochrone_polys[0]`. The coordinates of `isochrone_polys[0]` seem to be projected, but not sure which projection. However it gets picked up by default in QGIS as WGS84, then is in the wrong place. I have updated the question with this information.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I haven't used the data from the `bbox` section in this. Everything is run from the `place` which is just a centroid of the suburb. Whlie the `edges` has a CRS, the polygon doesn't. `AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'crs'`

Comment: Shapely geometry doesn't include CRS. `+proj=utm +zone=55 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
` is a proj4 format CRS, so when you create shapefile, change 4326 to 32755, and check the result.

Comment: I exported it with the crs of 32755. When I imported it in to QGIS, it didn't pick it up and defaulted in to WGS84. I manually changed it in to 32755, but that isn't the right one either.

Comment: Could you export isochrone_polys[0] as a wkt format to a txt file, so I may try to import it to a shapefile and check whether it can work or not? `isochrone_polys[0].wkt`

Comment: I have added those to the github repo.

Comment: @william3031, check the new update code and screenshot. Hope it works this time.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks heaps for the work you've put in to answering the question.