# Is it possible to create a shapefile from a geometry with Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, google-earth-engine, geojson, shapely

I use a GEE asset to describe the geometry of a country. I can transform this geometry into different format such as shapely.geometry or GeoJSON:

```py
asset = 'users/bornToBeAlive/aoi_PU'

aoi = ee.FeatureCollection(asset)
aoiJson = geemap.ee_to_geojson(aoi)
aoiShp = sg.shape(aoiJson['features'][0]['geometry'])

rootDir = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/'
```

Unfortunately the `gdal.warp` function requires a shapefile as input. Is there a way to export these structure to a shapefile ?

**EDIT**

```py
# Now convert it to a shapefile with OGR    
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('Esri Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource(rootDir + 'my.shp')
layer = ds.CreateLayer('', None, ogr.wkbPolygon)
# Add one attribute
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger))
defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()

# Create a new feature (attribute and geometry)
feat = ogr.Feature(defn)
feat.SetField('id', 123)

# Make a geometry, from Shapely object
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(aoiShp.wkb)
feat.SetGeometry(geom)

layer.CreateFeature(feat)
feat = geom = None  # destroy these

# Save and close everything
ds = layer = feat = geom = None
```

I tried to use this solution but I obtain a very small version of my geometry centered in [0,0] when I open it in QGIS, am I missing something ?

Comment: does this work? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/how-to-write-shapely-geometries-to-shapefiles

Comment: I've tested the method of this link but when I open my sapefile in QGIS to check it's the appropriate geometry but super small and centered at the [0,0] point, did I miss something ?

Comment: What projection (EPSG) do you use?

Comment: To display it in QGIS I need to manually add 'ESPG: 4326' is it possible to add it to `ds` ?

Comment: `gdal.warp function requires a shapefile as input` is the function the same as `gdalwarp`?

Comment: I assume, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in order to create a shapefile from an ee asset I propose the following solution, feel free to improve it :

```py
rootDir = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/'

asset = 'users/bornToBeAlive/aoi_PU'

aoi = ee.FeatureCollection(asset)
aoiJson = geemap.ee_to_geojson(aoi)
aoiShp = sg.shape(aoiJson['features'][0]['geometry'])
```

Then you need to create your shapefile (it will be encoded in UTF-8)

```py
# Now convert it to a shapefile with OGR    
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('Esri Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource(rootDir + 'my.shp')
layer = ds.CreateLayer('', None, ogr.wkbPolygon)
# Add one attribute
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger))
defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()

# Create a new feature (attribute and geometry)
feat = ogr.Feature(defn)
feat.SetField('id', 123)

# Make a geometry, from Shapely object
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(aoiShp.wkb)
feat.SetGeometry(geom)

layer.CreateFeature(feat)
feat = geom = None  # destroy these

# Save and close everything
ds = layer = feat = geom = None
```

Finally add a projection file to avoid projection error when displaying or using:

```py
#add the spatial referecence
spatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
spatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

spatialRef.MorphToESRI()
file = open(rootDir + 'my.prj', 'w')
file.write(spatialRef.ExportToWkt())
file.close()
```

and then you are good to go !